# lazysizes need to work for only device width. not for device height

Tags: javascript, html, css, lazy-loading, responsive

I have a problem with https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes

```
<img class="figure-image lazyload"
    src="{{ image.src|resizeDynamic(800) }}"
    srcset="{{ placeholderImage(800, 800 / image.aspect) }}"
    data-srcset="
      {{ image.src|resizeDynamic(1920) }} 1920w,
      {{ image.src|resizeDynamic(1440) }} 1440w,
      {{ image.src|resizeDynamic(1320) }} 1320w,
      {{ image.src|resizeDynamic(1024) }} 1024w,
      {{ image.src|resizeDynamic(800) }} 800w,
      {{ image.src|resizeDynamic(600) }} 600w,
      {{ image.src|resizeDynamic(375) }} 375w"
    data-sizes="auto"
    alt="{{ image.alt|e }}">
```

on browser, above image works for only width. but on mobile, it is considering about the max value of device's width and device's height.

for example, iPhoneX have a 375 x 812 demension. but on portrait mode (width 375px), image is pulling **for {{ image.src|resizeDynamic(1024) }} 1024w.** , **not pulling 375px width image**. I thought that it is working for max value for real device. also on landspace mode (width 812px), image is pulling for  **{{ image.src|resizeDynamic(1920) }} 1920w,**

this is very strange thing. I attached images about my issues.

[image]

[image]

[image]

but I want to make this considering about device's width like PC.

I was googling for this thing. it recommend me Picture tag like the following

```
<picture>
    <source data-srcset="assets/imgs/6.jpg" media="(max-width: 500px)" />
    <source data-srcset="assets/imgs/7.jpg" media="(max-width: 1024px)" />
    <source data-srcset="assets/imgs/9.jpg" />
    <img
        class="lazyload"
        data-src="assets/imgs/8.jpg"
        alt="image with artdirection" />
</picture>
```

but I think that using Picture tag seems to not good...

If any advice, please let me know thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS browsers behaviour might be correct here - it‘s pulling the bigger / wider images as it has a higher density display (retina) and that for would need an image asset with a bigger resolution (2x and even 3x depending in the iPhone). This is as well comparable to other browsers implementations.